# Managed Windows Service starts up slowly after digital signing

Tags: .net, performance, .net-4.0, digital-signature, authenticode

We recently tried out digitally signing our .NET binaries. We have a Windows Service which typically starts up within 10 seconds. However after we started digitally signing it, the time increased to around 20-30 seconds.

Googling led to me this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936707 which basically says that I have to set generatePublisherEvidence  to false.

But the [description of generatePublisherEvidence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb629393%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN points to the fact that this is not applicable for .NET 4. Still I tried out this setting and it did work. I double checked that my binaries do target .NET 4.

Can someone please explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the steps mentioned in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936707 which basically says that I have to set **generatePublisherEvidence** to *false* in my application's App.Config.

**Edit:** As per ssdi's answer, the root cause of the delay is because:

> This problem occurs because the application must download the
>   Certificate Revocation List (CRL) for authentication. However, a lack
>   of network connectivity causes the download to fail by timing out. For
>   example, a firewall may potentially block the download. When Windows
>   first starts, the network connection is not yet initialized.

See also article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941990 for more details.

Answer (score 9):

I was in a similar situation: An authenticode-signed application on a server without internet
access had an unexplained significant startup delay. Setting the **generatePublisherEvidence** to
false seemed to solve the issue, but I was unable to a definitive explanation of why this was
necessary.

Microsoft's [documentation of the generatePublisherEvidence-element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/generatepublisherevidence-element)
confused me with these two notes:

> In the .NET Framework 4 and later, this element has no effect on assembly load times.

and

> We recommend that services use the  element to improve startup performance. Using this element can also help avoid delays that can cause a time-out and the cancellation of the service startup.

After a lengthy investigation, using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon),
[Certutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc732443(v=ws.11))
and debugging into [.NET Framework source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/), my conclusion is:

**The generatePublisherEvidence element is definetely still relevant for .NET 4, even 4.7 which I was using!
It is just no longer the case that without it the signature is always verified by the runtime as part of
the assembly loading process, but the signature verification might still be triggered (unintentionally) at some point!**

Read on for more details.

---

### .NET 2 and 3.5

A digital signature would always be verified when an assembly was loaded, as part of the
initialization of the so-called evidence objects used by the Code Access Security (CAS) mechanism.
The publisher evidence, which is the one created from the digital signature, was by default
not used in CAS, so most of the times this was just a waste of time. And as
explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/application-startup-time#optimize-authenticode):

> Authenticode verification adds to the startup time. Authenticode-signed assemblies have
>   to be verified with the certification authority (CA). This verification can be time consuming,
>   because it can require connecting to the network several times to download current certificate
>   revocation lists. It also makes sure that there is a full chain of valid certificates on the
>   path to a trusted root. This can translate to several seconds of delay while the assembly is being loaded.
>
> Consider installing the CA certificate on the client computer, or avoid using Authenticode
>   when it is possible. If you know that your application does not need the publisher evidence,
>   you do not have to pay the cost of signature verification.
>
> Starting in .NET Framework 3.5, there is a configuration option that allows the Authenticode
>   verification to be bypassed. To do this, add the following setting to the app.exe.config file:
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>   <runtime>
>     <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
>   </runtime>
> </configuration>
> ```

### .NET 4

The initialization of evidence objects are now [delayed until actually needed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103(v=vs.100).aspx#evidence_collection),
to avoid the startup penalty this lead to in previous versions. This means digital signatures are no longer
always verified during assembly loading process. But it turns out there are cases where all evidence objects are
being initialized, including the rarely used publisher evidence!

In my case I had an application which was using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library to
query a database on startup. This library relies on a specific configuration section
("oracle.manageddataaccess.client") in the application configuration. For some reason I did
not include such a configuration in my app.config file (nor in my machine.config).

When asked for this configuration section, the System.Configuration assembly, responsible
for accessing the configurations, will first look in the machine.config, and then
in the application config. When it does not find the requested section in either of these
it looks for user-specific configuration files, located in a subfolder path of %AppData%.
The full path to these files includes the strong name of the assembly, so therefore the
strong name evidence must be created.

**The System.Configuration assembly then decides that all evidence objects must be initialized.**

Since my application was digitally signed this included initializing the publisher evidence,
which means verifying the signature, with CRL checks and all that comes with it.
The publisher evidence is not actually used, only the strong name evidence is part of the path to the
user configuration files, so again this is just a waste of time.

Adding the "oracle.manageddataaccess.client" section to my app.config file avoided this, the
complete set of evidence objects did not have to be initialized, and the digital signature would
no longer verified. The startup delay was gone.

**In general, setting the generatePublisherEvidence element to false makes sure the publisher
evidence is not included whenever the framework decides that the evidence objects must be initialized!**

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is caused by OCSP and CRL checks being performed for the certificate used for signing. This can increase time significantly. Unfortunately we found no way to disable those checks (and anyway such disabling leads to potential security problems) so we simply don't sign the assemblies with Authenticode but simply strong-name them.

Comment: The check can be disabled by setting generatePublisherEvidence to false. However, MSDN says this does not affect .NET 4 apps, but it did help my app.

Comment: @GaneshR. this settings seems to be different from disabling OCSP/CRL checks. It seems to turn off checking altogether.

Comment: If you read the MSDN article it says that the checks disabled by generatePublisherEvidence are only required when you use Publisher class. Which in turn is required only by Partial trust applications. I have a Full Trust desktop application. Will there be any security related disadvantages that I may face?

Comment: @GaneshR. We are talking about different things. I was pointing that the OCSP and CRL checks are part of certificate validation process, but checking of the signature itself is another important part. And if you disable checking altogether with this attribute, what's the sense in signing the module then? MSDN doesn't say anything about OCSP or CRLs in particular.

Answer (score 0):

See also article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941990

> This problem occurs because the application must download the Certificate Revocation List (CRL) for authentication. However, a lack of network connectivity causes the download to fail by timing out. For example, a firewall may potentially block the download. When Windows first starts, the network connection is not yet initialized.

Comment: Thanks. I will include that in my answer.