# set generatePublisherEvidence false as default

Tags: c#, winforms

`generatePublisherEvidence` will cause a long startup time in some cases, and I would like to turn it off.

With app.config, I could deal with it by below.

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Though accomplishable, it looks redundant. 
It is more natural that `generatePublisherEvidence` is turned false by default. In other words, no app.config is required. 
But I could not find any setting about it in Visual Studio 2012.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In .Net 4.0 and newer, when running in a "full trust" environment this should always be pretty much disabled.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you need to turn it off is because the .NET framework turns it [on by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393.aspx). The documentation is clear on that.

However, please also take note to this:

> In the .NET Framework 4 and later, this element has no effect on assembly load times. For more information, see the "Security Policy Simplification" section in Security Changes in the .NET Framework.

That's from the same documentation link. If you can upgrade to .NET 4+ you're good leaving it on.

Comment: From my experience of today, with an app build in .net 4.6.1. It makes a differences. All signed stuff that used EF6 takes some time to start when generatePublisherEvidence = true. I'm still trying to understand why but seems that EF6 code try to contact the third party implied in the signature of our certificate.

Answer (score 0):

See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354387/9243364), where I explain why this is still relevant with .NET 4!

> The generatePublisherEvidence element is definetely still relevant for .NET 4, even 4.7 which I was using! It is just no longer the case that without it the signature is always verified by the runtime as part of the assembly loading process, but the signature verification might still be triggered (unintentionally) at some point!